# working with jquery.panzoom.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to implement pinch to zoom and drag functionality for mobile website, So I picked up a jquery plugin downloaded from this source https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom .

Requirement is just pinch to zoom-in and zoom-out and drag I am not having any button to call this event. I am not getting any proper explanation on this from the docs. I am writing this piece of code :

*jQuery(document).ready(function() {*

$(".panzoom").panzoom("zoom");

});

Can any one  help me to get it worked. Thanks in advance .

Comment: what is not working ? Any errors ? to identify events like pinchin or other touch events you may want to check `hammerjs` http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Comment: Thanks for your reply used hammer js and it worked smoothly .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hammer js solved my problem. Thanks all.

Comment: Can you post some code? How did you solve this with Hammer?

Answer (score 1):

jquery.panzoom.js now support pinch for zooming, you can check in on the [demo page](http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/)

Comment: Demo page only has mousewheel-controlled zoom demo. No specific mention of "pinch". I'm struggling to see whether pinch must be enabled by writing your own code, in addition to the basic instantiation of panzoom.